# FontMetrics setFont?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, fontmetrics

I am making a program in which I need to set the Font inside a FontMetrics object. I have already created the fontmetrics before, but now I don't have access to the Graphics object anymore. Yet, I want to change the font inside the FontMetrics, that is, create a new FontMetrics, with a new Font, but using the same Graphic context.

I could make the Graphics avaliable, but it would take a lot of time and it wouldn't make sense at all to do so. Would anyone know an easier way to it? It seens so obvius it should be a way, maybe I am just missing something really stupid (I looked at the documentation and found nothing).

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest way would be to use [`JComponent.getFontMetrics(Font)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getFontMetrics%28java.awt.Font%29). This method respects the `JComponent`'s current `FontRenderContext` (Note:`Component.getFontMetrics` will *not* respect the current `FontRenderContext`).

Comment: That would not work, as I also don't have access to the Component, since the class I am making is a persistence class. I could, as I said, make the Graphics global, but I was thinking maybe there was some better way.