# Java Graphics: Constructing FontMetrics from Font, without a Graphics2D

Tags: java, swing, fonts, awt, fontmetrics

### Known

Given [`FontMetrics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html)

There is a protected constructor for `FontMetrics` from `Font`.

### Question:

Given a `Font` object, is there a way to construct a `FontMetrics` object without going through `Graphics2D.setFont`, `Graphics2D.getFontMetric()`?

### Context

I'm playing with a TeX like rendering algorithm. I need to calculate bounding boxes & the such for various characters from a *.pfb file. I can construct a Font object from the *.pfb file. I need a `FontMetrics` object to get the ascent, descent, width. It just seems very ugly for me to have to construct an unused intermediate Graphics object just to get at the `FontMetrics`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FontMetrics setFont?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674035/fontmetrics-setfont)

Comment: Why is it a duplicate? That guy is fine using a Graphics object. For me, I specifically want to avoid creating Graphics objects.

Comment: No, he wants to avoid using a `Graphics` instance if at all possible.

Comment: He already used the Graphics object to construct the FontMetrics. (Thus, he's okay with using it). He just doesn't want to continue to pass it around. I don't want to touch Graphics in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Given a `Font` object, is there a way to construct a `FontMetrics` object without going through `Graphics2D.setFont`, `Graphics2D.getFontMetric()`?

See [`BufferedImage.createGraphics()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#createGraphics%28%29) or [`getGraphics()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getGraphics%28%29) for an alternative way to get the `Graphics` instance.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I noticed you edited the link from Java 6 to Java 7. I'm actually stuck on Java 6 for stupid reasons. Should I tag my question differently to specify that I have to use Java 6?

Comment: The same doc from Java 7 apply to Java 6, unless they state `@since 1.7` I feel it is best to link to the latest Java Docs no matter what version you are targeting.  It is sometimes handy to mention the minimum version, but Java 7 is still new enough that most people will think to add *"if the user can run Java 7, you can use..".* As it is, I still code for Java 6 or below.  It will be a while before I would consider adding any 1.7+ functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Or completely without the use of the graphics object:

```
Font font = new Font("Helvetica",Font.PLAIN,12);
Canvas c = new Canvas();
FontMetrics fm = c.getFontMetrics(font);
```

If you now call `c.getGraphics()` it will return null. This (canvas) will also work in [headless mode](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html).