# How do I get the height and width of a text printed on a 300 dpi label printer?

Tags: java

I need to print a text, e.g. "Product name" to a label, printed by a 300 dpi label printer, from JAVA.
The font is Arial. FontSize 6.
How do I calculate the width of the text (in mm)?

```
String fontName = "Arial";
int fontSize = 6;
String string = "Product name";
Font font = new Font(fontName, Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
Canvas c = new Canvas();
FontMetrics fm = c.getFontMetrics(font);
int i = fm.stringWidth(string);
```

In the above code, i=36. But what does "36" mean? How can I get the width in milimeters, when printed on a label with a 300DPI printer?

Comment: where is your code which you had tried?

Comment: I tried this, but got confused with the graphics2D:    String str = "Hello World";
    Font font = new Font("Arial", 0, 6);
    Graphics2D ig2;
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(150, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    ig2 = bi.createGraphics();
    Rectangle2D r2D = font.getStringBounds(str, ig2.getFontRenderContext());

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your question is calling `new Canvas()` which is going to assume that your screen is the intended output device, creating potential for different behavior on different systems.

[This doc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/java2dpart1-137217.html) explicitly says user space in Java 2D is intended to be 72 units per inch. The Javadoc for FontMetrics isn't explicit about the unit it is returning, but it makes sense for it to be user space coordinates. That means the 36 you're seeing is 36/72 inch, which is 12.7 mm.

**Update 2:**

Your question didn't say how you were getting the rendered text to the printer, so you may already have a Graphics or Graphics2D object from which to get the font metrics in the context of the actual output device. If you don't, the following code should create a graphics context independent of the screen:

```
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 6));
    int width = fm.stringWidth("Product name");
```

The result is still 36, in units of 1/72 inch.

**Update 3:**

In the image below, the string "NCW" is shown in Arial as rendered by Java. The bottom of the rectangle is the baseline, and the bottom left corner of the rectangle is the point where I told Java to draw the string. The width of the rectangle is output of `fm.stringWidth()` as above. (The top of the rectangle is arbitrary.) You can see that the string width is not about the points where the text touches the baseline, but neither is it the distance from the left-most to the right-most filled-in pixel. Rather, it is the rightward advance along the baseline from where this string was drawn to where the next string would normally be drawn.

[image: Image produced by short Java program to demonstrate stringWidth]

The spacing between the C and the W is a nice example of kerning. The font designer also choose to have the bottom edge of the C extend slightly below the baseline, because round shapes don't look visually aligned with straight ones unless you cheat. Notice how there's some space to the left of the N and much less space to the right of the W. This is for the same reason there's less space between the C and the W: to make it look right. If the font designer had wanted to, he could have had the W extend beyond the box, just like the C extends below it.

The end result is that the visual weight of the letter forms should be evenly distributed, so the center of that box should be the visual center of the text. So you should be able to ignore everything I just said, add half the string width to the starting point, call that the center, and be happy.

If the result doesn't look centered to you, then either you have the math wrong, or something in your printing code isn't doing what you think it's doing, or the font designer simply didn't balance the visual weight to your liking. If the latter, feel free to apply some artistic license and fudge it over to where you like it.

Comment: Thanks for your post. Is there any way, where I can be sure to get the correct width of a text, then?

Comment: @JakobMathiasen Updated answer with the code I would use to get the width of a string.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I can use this.. A small problem is, that the stringWidth("xxx") method gives the length from the starting point on the baseline to the ending point on the baseline, and not from the overall starting point to end point. And in all documentations about this, they all say that I can't rely on the result by taking the width of each char and add them together..

Comment: @JakobMathiasen The reason you can't add the widths of the individual characters is that fonts have kerning adjustments for pairs of characters like AV and XO. So assuming you print the text as complete strings (rather than one character at a time), `stringWidth` returns the answer you want. If by overall width you're referring to the way the top-left corner of a W is allowed to  start slightly to the left of the starting point, that's a subtle detail that requires you to think in units smaller than mm.

Comment: It is exactly "W" that gave me the problem. I need to center the text NCW within a rectangle. But the stringWidth("NCW") gives me the witdth at the baseline. So when I center the text, it doesn't seem centered because of the top right corner of the "W". Still I don't know how to calculate this correct.

Comment: @JakobMathiasen updated again to try to address your last commment

Answer (score 1):

The class you want is [`FontMetrics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html), which you can get from your `Graphics2D` object.

Once you've got the FontMetrics object, you can use methods like `charsWidth`, `getHeight`, and `getAscent` to determine the appropriate width and height of your string (depending on what you mean by 'height,' see the explanation on page 73 [here](http://oreilly.com/openbook/javawt/book/ch03.pdf) to understand some of the basics about font sizing) in pixels.

Pixels, as you know, aren't the same as inches-on-paper -- but if you know the DPI of your printer, you should be able to determine size in inches through division: pixels / DPI = inches.

Comment: is there a way to avoid the Graphics2D, when I want to calculate the width of the string?

Comment: I think you're asking something along the lines of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677876/java-graphics-constructing-fontmetrics-from-font-without-a-graphics2d

Comment: Thanks for the link. When I implement this I get (example) stringWidth("product name") = 37. But what does "37" mean in this context? 37 pixels? 37/300 = 0.1233 inches = 3.1 mm. But the string is actualy 12 mm on the label..

Comment: Without your code, it's hard to tell. It sounds like you've got another rescaling (4x) in there somewhere.  Can you post *all* your code, from where you grab the FontMetrics all the way up to where you send it to the printer?